# Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256[1] storage ref

Tags: solidity

hi there so i keep getting this error `Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in uint256[1] storage ref.` and im not sure how to fix it. The error occrus at `_ownedTokens[to].push(tokenId);`

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import './ERC721.sol';

contract ERC721Enumerable is ERC721{

    uint256[] private _allTokens;

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _allTokensIndex;
    mapping(address => uint256[1]) private _ownedTokens;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _ownedTokensIndex;

    function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721) {
        super._mint(to, tokenId);
        _addTokensToAllTokenEnumeration(tokenId);
        _addTokensToOwnerEnumeration(to, tokenId);
    }

    function _addTokensToAllTokenEnumeration(uint256 tokenId) private {
        _allTokensIndex[tokenId] = _allTokens.length;
        _allTokens.push(tokenId);
    }

    function _addTokensToOwnerEnumeration(address to, uint256 tokenId) private {
        _ownedTokensIndex[tokenId] = _ownedTokens[to].length;
        _ownedTokens[to].push(tokenId);
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns(uint256) {
        return _allTokens.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_ownedTokens` is a mapping that point to a `uint256[1]`. This is an array with the fixed length of 1. Therefore this array doesn't support `push` as the length cabnot be adjusted.

If you want to be able to add/remove items, then you should declare it as a dynamic array `uint256[]`.

Comment: omg it was that simple. Thank you so much!